How can Large Language Model AIs help with Hermeneutics?
In this question, I would like to explore techniques when AIs like ChatGPT could help with Hermeneutics.
What kind of prompts did you use for what kind of goals?
How did you lead the conversation with AIs like ChatGPT to weed out as many mistakes as possible?
(Note: There is this question What should you not do when using Large Language Models in the field of Hermeneutics? that explores the dangers of AIs like ChatGPT as it relates to Hermeneutics, so answers that point to the dangers, mistakes, and disadvantages that AIs certainly have, are out of the scope of this question).

The site tour specifically states that Asking about Hermeneutical approaches is "on topic" and I believe that Using an LLM is certainly one tool for or approach to Hermeneutics. As such, I have voted to leave this one open.

This basically it just does what scholars already do but faster, and it has the same advantages and pitfalls that already exist.  With today's Bible software, people can do in a day what used to be a person's dissertation.

I don't like seeing answers from ChatGPT here, and am considering deleting them.

@curiousdannii I think this question is a bit of a special case. While I agree that the final answer should add their thoughts and contextualization to the answer I still think letting an LLM make a case for themself is a valid approach. I also would put a bit of leeway since that is the first question (to my knowledge) that specifically asks about the usage of LLMs in hermeneutics, so I am not sure if there is a proper policy in place for such a question other than marking an LLM answer as one.

@curiousdannii   I think it would be also fair if you create an example answer (or reference an existing one) of what you would expect of an answer that uses LLMs in BH.Meta or create an answer here that does not "misuse" LLMs.

@curiousdannii on the other hand I see the point that LLMs might not be a sufficient source to answer this question either. It's complicated...

No, there's no reason this question should be an exception. If you want to ask an AI about itself go ahead, but this site is for humans.

@curiousdannii I opened a discussion regarding LLM texts in answers: https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5128/what-do-answers-that-feature-a-llm-based-text-have-to-include-as-well-to-not-be

And here's how ChatGPT responds to your question:

Artificial Intelligence (AI) systems like ChatGPT can significantly
aid in the field of hermeneutics, which is the study and
interpretation of texts, especially religious or philosophical texts.
Here are several ways in which AI can assist with hermeneutics:

Text Analysis and Interpretation:


Pattern Recognition: AI can identify patterns, themes, and motifs within texts that may not be immediately apparent to human readers.

Contextual Understanding: By analyzing large corpora of related    texts, AI can provide context and background information that can
enhance understanding and interpretation.

Semantic Analysis: AI can dissect and analyze the semantics of a    text, helping to clarify meanings of ambiguous or complex passages.



Historical and Cultural Contextualization:


Cross-referencing Historical Data: AI can cross-reference texts with historical and cultural data to provide insights into the
conditions and contexts in which a text was written.

Language Evolution: AI can track changes in language and terminology over time, offering a more nuanced understanding of how certain terms
or concepts might have been understood in different historical
periods.



Comparative Analysis:


Parallel Texts: AI can compare multiple texts to identify similarities and differences, helping to highlight unique features or
common themes.

Intertextuality: AI can identify and analyze references, allusions, and influences between different texts, enriching the interpretative
process.



Linguistic Analysis:


Syntax and Grammar: AI can analyze the syntax and grammatical structure of texts, offering insights into the stylistic and
rhetorical techniques used by the author.
Translation and Multilingual Analysis: AI can translate texts into different languages and compare interpretations across languages,
helping to bridge linguistic gaps.


Access to Secondary Literature:


Summarizing Scholarly Work: AI can summarize existing scholarly work on a text, providing a comprehensive overview of various
interpretative approaches and debates.

Bibliographic Assistance: AI can help identify and organize relevant secondary literature, making it easier for researchers to
find and utilize sources.



Interactive and Collaborative Tools:


Interactive Exploration: Tools like ChatGPT can engage in interactive discussions with researchers, posing questions, offering
interpretations, and suggesting alternative perspectives.

Collaborative Platforms: AI can facilitate collaborative research by connecting scholars with similar interests and aiding in the
sharing of resources and ideas.



Automated Research Assistance:


Data Extraction: AI can extract relevant data points from large volumes of text, saving researchers time and effort.

Metadata Generation: AI can generate metadata for texts, such as keywords, summaries, and thematic tags, which can aid in organization
and retrieval.



Predictive and Prescriptive Analysis:


Trend Prediction: AI can predict trends in interpretation based on historical data, helping scholars anticipate future directions in
hermeneutic studies.

Prescriptive Analytics: AI can offer prescriptive insights by suggesting possible interpretations or methodological approaches based
on existing data.


While AI cannot replace the nuanced and subjective insights of human
interpreters, it can provide powerful tools and methodologies that
enhance and support the hermeneutic process. By leveraging AI,
scholars can gain deeper and more comprehensive insights into texts,
leading to richer and more informed interpretations.

Yikes!

Okay, so instead of speculating what the results might contain or where they might fall short, I entered the identical question into ChatGPT 3.5, Microsoft Copilot (which is ChatGPT 4o based), Google Gemini, and Perplexity AI:
In Revelation 19:9, who do the guests to the wedding supper of the lamb consist of?

ChatGPT 3.5:

Revelation 19:9 refers to the "wedding supper of the Lamb," a
significant event in Christian eschatology. The guests invited to this
celebration are often interpreted in various ways within Christian
theology. Here are some common interpretations:

The Church: Many theologians believe that the guests at the wedding supper of the Lamb are the members of the Church, representing all
believers in Jesus Christ. This view sees the Church as the Bride of
Christ, and the wedding supper as the consummation of the relationship
between Christ and His Church.
Old Testament Saints: Another interpretation includes the Old Testament saints—those who had faith in God before the coming of
Christ. They, too, are seen as participants in this heavenly
celebration.
Tribulation Saints: Some interpretations extend the invitation to those who come to faith during the Great Tribulation, the period of
suffering and persecution described in the book of Revelation.
Angelic Hosts and Heavenly Beings: In addition to human participants, some interpretations include angels and other heavenly
beings as witnesses and celebrants of this event. The exact identity
of the guests can vary depending on theological perspectives, but they
generally encompass all those who are redeemed and have put their
faith in God, spanning different eras of salvation history. This event
symbolizes the ultimate union and fellowship of believers with Christ
in the eternal kingdom.



Copilot:

In Revelation 19:9, the guests invited to the wedding supper of the Lamb are often interpreted as the followers of Christ. The verse states, "Blessed are those who are invited to the marriage supper of the Lamb." This is generally understood to mean that those who have been called and have accepted the invitation to follow Christ (the Lamb) are the ones who will partake in this heavenly feast¹².
This interpretation is based on various passages in the New Testament where the relationship between Christ and the Church is described in terms of a marriage, with Christ as the bridegroom and the Church as the bride. The wedding supper, therefore, represents the ultimate union of Christ with His followers in the heavenly kingdom².
However, interpretations can vary, and some may see the guests as a specific group within the broader body of believers. It's also important to note that the book of Revelation is highly symbolic, and different scholars may interpret its imagery in different ways¹².
I hope this helps! If you have any more questions, feel free to ask. 
Source: Conversation with Copilot, 6/4/2024
(1) What does Revelation 19:9 mean? | BibleRef.com. https://www.bibleref.com/Revelation/19/Revelation-19-9.html.
(2) Revelation 19:9 Commentaries: Then he said to me, "Write, 'Blessed are .... https://biblehub.com/commentaries/revelation/19-9.htm.
(3) Revelation 19:9 - Verse-by-Verse Bible Commentary - StudyLight.org. https://www.studylight.org/commentary/revelation/19-9.html.
(4) Revelation 19:9 - Bible Verse Meaning and Commentary - Bible Study Tools. https://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/gills-exposition-of-the-bible/revelation-19-9.html.


Gemini:

The specific identities of the guests at the marriage supper of the Lamb in Revelation 19:9 are not explicitly mentioned in the verse itself. However, there are some clues and interpretations within Christian theology:

The Bridegroom: The Lamb is a symbolic name for Jesus Christ (John 1:29).
The Bride: The bride is referred to as the Church, consisting of believers in Jesus (Revelation 21:2).

Possible Guests:

Believers in Christ:  This is a common interpretation,  referring to both those alive at the Second Coming and those who have already died. Their good deeds are described as "fine linen, bright and pure" (Revelation 19:8).
Old Testament Saints:  Some interpretations include righteous figures from the Old Testament based on references like Matthew 8:11.

Overall:
The passage emphasizes the blessedness of being invited, rather than giving a specific guest list.


Perplexity:
Perplexity also includes footnotes for every assertion, including the sources and excerpts, which in this case are: bibleref, israelmyglory, biblegateway, oncedelivered, and bibletools!
In Revelation 19:9, who do the guests to the wedding supper of the lamb consist of?

According to the biblical passages and commentaries, the guests
invited to the wedding supper of the Lamb in Revelation 19:9 are
understood to consist of:

Old Testament saints and believers
Tribulation saints and believers who come to faith during the end times
Heavenly beings like angels who witness the marriage of Christ and the Church

The key points are:
Old Testament Saints
Many interpret the guests to include Old Testament figures like
Abraham, Isaac, Jacob, John the Baptist, and other faithful believers
from before the Church age. John the Baptist referred to himself as
the "friend of the bridegroom" who rejoices at the bridegroom's
(Christ's) voice.
Tribulation Believers
A common view is that the guests also encompass those who come to
faith in Christ during the tribulation period, after the Church has
been raptured to heaven.
Heavenly Witnesses
Some suggest the guests could be heavenly beings like angels who
marvel at God's redemptive work, though they are not the recipients of
salvation themselves. The bride herself is understood to be the
Church, distinct from the invited guests. The marriage supper
celebrates the union of Christ and His bride (the Church) after the
rapture, with the guests as witnesses and participants in the joyous
feast.


So, now it's up to you. Which of these synthesized/compiled answers are better and why?
Do any of these answers display any doctrinal preference or bias?
What would you conclude from reading these answers about using these engines as a study tool?

+1 for the most ironic and funny answer. Using ChatGPT here is an absolutely brilliant move. Well Played Sir.

Citation needed: This site is a little different than other sites around the web. In particular, pay attention to what constitutes a good answer and make sure your answer meets those guidelines. Please note that "showing your work" is required. But in all seriousness, you still have to do the legwork on showing your work.

ChatGPT is also going to be limited to public domain work. So, as an example, it would quote from lesser works as it doesn't have access to the HALOT or BDAG that have the benefit of decades more archeology and scholarship. It would not be able to incorporate the Word Biblical Commentary (for example), or other copyright protected works that are not digitally published and freely available on the internet and would suffer greatly in terms of quality answers as a result.

@James, Haha. Okay, here's my work: 1. Login to chatbot website, 2. Copy-paste in the question, 3. Copy-paste the answer into BH. Incidentally, I love a plate of irony lightly seasoned with a little sarcasm.

@James, but chatbots would have access to what other people found in those valuable resources.  :o

@Dieter - assuming they quoted it or summarized it, yes. But in terms of an original answer, ChatGPT would not have the foundational material needed to create such an answer.

Dieter - But it would have no way of discerning which position to correctly interpret the material, unless the human programmer chooses with bias which doctrine the chatbot should prefer over all else, just like Constantine at Nicea.

@JoshuaB I would submit to you that any good, complete answer would summarize all major viewpoints. In your example, both Athanasius and Arius - and modern views on the Nicene creed should be represented and and a note on which is the majority opinion and consensus made (and why). I'm not sure that one viewpoint should be "chosen" or why an answer should be intentionally biased. The goal should be to remove any bias while fully representing the topic.

Can anyone think of a good, incisive question for a chatbot that might expose preference or prejudice regarding any scholarly position on it without eliciting a massive answer?

@JamesShewey But the AI will naturally pick the majority opinion of the texts, which will naturally be the pro-Trinitarian slant on every contested passage. The AI is programmed to simply choose the majority opinion on all texts, and it is impossible for it to make theological choices on its own, without external intervention. Basically the AI will create arrogant monsters who will become even more confident of their doctrinal delusions.

@Dieter I think you can get that by using questions that contain prejudice in the first place because the AI simply mirrors you or categorizes you. So your challenge is even more difficult because you also have to prove that your prompt is free of preference and prejudice as well.

@There are numerous ways to hack/trick ChatGPT into giving answers it normally would not, and sometimes AI "Hallucinates" or programmers mess up their attempts to remove bias that gives funky answers. So it's not impossible - but generally that will not be the default.

StackExchange needs a new Badge:  For providing an answer which most people find pleasant) that is "almost, but not quite, entirely unlike ChatGPT.".   With a tip of the hat to Douglas Adams.  :-)

Okay, I edited my answer to include a sample question that I fed to both ChatGPT and Perplexity. You be the judge.

@JoshuaB If GenAI was only going to parrot the dominant position then it wouldn't be so frequently wrong. Now whether it's more likely to report a minority position than to just completely make something up I don't know.

@curiousdannii - I just conversed with ChatGPT and it couldn't even decide between over another. Very underdeveloped and maybe impossible and quite untrustworthy.

@Dieter I added a discussion here about how to deal with LLMs in answers: https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5128/what-do-answers-that-feature-a-llm-based-text-have-to-include-as-well-to-not-be

I got a more useful answer than @Dieter did when I limited the question to "biblical hermeneutics." The second bullet point is the one that responds most directly in the sense that the term "biblical hermeneutics" is used on this site. Everything below is written by A.I. - including the illustration:



Here are some ways in which ChatGPT can contribute to this field:

Immediate Access to Biblical Wisdom: ChatGPT provides a powerful tool that saves time and offers immediate access to biblical wisdom.
Instead of sifting through numerous articles and sources, users can
interact with ChatGPT to get insights directly from its extensive
knowledge base.

Interpretation of Bible Passages: Interpreting the Bible is a nuanced and multifaceted endeavor. ChatGPT can offer diverse
perspectives from different schools of thought, both Christian and
non-Christian. Users can ask ChatGPT to list interpretations of
specific passages, gaining insights into various theological
viewpoints.

Exploring Ethical Perspectives: ChatGPT’s conception of humanist ethics can be explored using biblical passages. For instance, it can
engage in discussions about variable interpretations of Bible verses,
a common theme in contemporary apologetics. By examining ethical
implications, ChatGPT contributes to the broader conversation about
biblical hermeneutics.


In summary, ChatGPT’s extensive knowledge base and ability to provide
diverse perspectives make it a valuable companion for anyone studying
biblical texts and seeking deeper insights into their meaning and
significance.


A blind machine will never understand the spiritual word of God.
God's word will never be understood by a cold machine programmed by a cold human who lacks the wisdom of God through spiritual regeneration. AI computes data blindly without applying anything through spiritual direction, because it does not have the wisdom which is present within the heart, the soul, and the spirit of a born-again man of God.
An AI machine system would merely compile the pre-existing mass of data and always choose with bias the majority texts without using any critical hermeneutic comprehension.
I have a fitting set of passages to share with you all:
Joshua 8:18, 8:26, 8:28, 8:29 ESV

Then the LORD said to Joshua, “Stretch out the javelin that is in your hand toward AI, for I will give it into your hand.”
Joshua did not draw back his hand with which he stretched out the
javelin until he had devoted all the inhabitants of AI to destruction.
So Joshua burned AI and made it forever a heap of ruins, as it is to
this day.
And he hanged the king of AI on a tree until evening. And at sunset
Joshua commanded, and they took his body down from the tree and threw
it at the entrance of the gate of the city and raised over it a great
heap of stones, which stands there to this day.


I created this question for how Chatgpt could help with hermeneutics.
I created another question for negative aspects of AI: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/95242/what-not-to-do-with-chatgpt
Please post your answer there.
