What should you not do when using Large Language Models in the field of Hermeneutics?
In this question, I want to explore, what techniques or prompts used with AIs like ChatGPT can lead to wrong hermeneutics.
The focus is on pitfalls that one can fall into or intuitive prompts that someone might use, which will lead to wrong interpretations.
(Similar to How can AIs like Large Language Models help with Hermeneutics?, answers that specifically focus on the advantages of AIs are out of scope in this question.)

the question seems kind of interesting but as asked is off toping for biblical hermeneutics. Maybe the meta site?

@AviAvraham  Yeah I also pondered on this a bit. I actually asked a related question on meta. https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5126/how-trustworthy-is-chatgpt-3-5-gpt-4o-and-gpt-4-with-bible-quotes I would still argue that this question belongs here because it is about a novel hermeneutical technique, that simply needs exploring. Surely questions about hermeneutical techniques are in the scope of BH.SE?

A big negative in my opinion is that ever assuming ChatGPT or other chatbot is absolutely 100% correct, it doesn't allow us to wrestle with the questions ourselves, which I think is extremely valuable. It's like finding out that "Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything" is 42.

The thing that bothers me is that they will give the AI chatbot all the texts, and it will simply choose the biased majority readings instead of using deep critical thinking and choose the oldest minority readings, and not all of them are the same, so we must choose the obvious remnant reading that meshes with Scripture before it's corrupted emendations.

@AviAvraham - I disagree. The site tour specifically states that Asking about Hermeneutical approaches is "on topic" and I believe that Using an LLM is certainly one tool for or approach to Hermeneutics. As such, I have voted to leave this one open.

ChatGPT is severely limited to public domain work. So, as an example, it would quote from lesser works as it doesn't have access to the HALOT or BDAG that have the benefit of decades more archeology and scholarship.
This has very meaningful impact on hermeneutics in many cases - even leading to outright wrong answers which can proceed from false premises based on outdated information.
ChatGPT would also not be able to incorporate the Word Biblical Commentary (for example), or other copyright protected works that are not digitally published and freely available on the internet and would suffer greatly in terms of quality answers as a result. As an example, this answer would have been impossible without access to the Coffin Text spell translations, and I had to visit a library to get them. ChatGPT would have been unable to formulate a similar answer.
Finally, ChatGTP has been known to generate false citations.
As such, while ChatGPT can provide a great starting place (much like Wikipedia content), the work of LLMs does need to be vetted and verified much like Wikipedia content). Perhaps even built upon (much like Wikipedia content) It can't simply be relied upon to be accurate out of the box - one cannot simply copy and pasted ChatGPT output.
Another common problem is that AI can suffer from so-called "hallucinations" which may give faulty answers. Similarly, problems with AI can result in "biased" answers. For example, at one point the Gemini Large Language Model (LLM) by Google was giving clearly biased results.† It is therefore also incumbent on a user to vet that ChatGPT or similar LLMs are not suffering a hallucination or training error.

† Note: The author of this linked Op-Ed piece attributes this to "left leaning bias" the reality is that in most cases, this is an attempt to train bias out of the algorithms. For example, AI facial recognition algorithms have a well-known and problematic issue with racial bias In all likelihood, a technician/programmer was likely trying to correct for something like this, and after retraining the AI model,  it "hallucinated" or was just plain was malfunctioning as a result of the additional training and changes had to be rolled back. It seems many of those conservative pundits who were decrying bias and political correctness had little understanding of the technical side of these kinds of results.

Yes, from my experimenting with it, I concluded 1) It really wants to impress and please you and give the answer you seem to want; 2) If necessary, it will lie in order to do that.

@RayButterworth - Do you have any examples?

@JamesShewey, my two favourites are: Did "The Prisoner" TV show and "The Ruling Class" film have any cast or crew in common?:
No, but it lied and said Patrick McGoohan was in "The Ruling Class", which would have been a perfect answer for me (a "Dry Bones" scene appeared in both productions).
¶ Do sets of relatively prime integers form a matroid?:
No, but it gave an superficially correct proof, and more impressively invented the term "coprime matroid".

A major goal for me in all my questions and answers here is to absolutely avoid any coprime matroids whenever possible!

@RayButterworth - It looks from your links like you are using ChatGPT 3.5 - The question about matrioids gives a different answer in ChatGPT 4. Using copilot (which is 4.0 based) it concludes that "the set of relatively prime integers does not satisfy the heredity property, and hence, does not form a matroid." It does still give the same answer regarding Patrick McGoohan though - linking to an IMDB article. Looking at IMDB though, McGoohan is not listed in the cast of The Ruling Class... Evidence of the false citations I mentioned.

First, a disclaimer:  I haven't directly used any LLM (Large Language Model).  My answer is based on many years of Software Engineering and also an intuitive understanding of Linguistics (as so I've been told by several Linguists).
You can't get ChatGPT to advance the science.   Basically, you can't get it to do PhD level work.  But, let me state simply what I mean by that.
PhD level work creates new information based on old information and applying a rational methodology.  I refer you to just about any PhD Thesis.  So, there's a deceptive danger where human beings will think, "Wow! That's smart."  The information is new to them, thus the surprise; but, it's actually information that is already known.  It's just communicated well.
Basically, I'm referencing Bloom's Hierarchy.  This hierarchy is ordered from the bottom of a pyramid to the top with:

Remember
Understand
Apply
Analyze
Evaluate
Create

Each level builds on the one above it (below it, on the pyramid).  ChatGPT doesn't get to level 6. Also, it doesn't Evaluate other than by consensus provided by input data.  So, there's a limitation--it's actually not intelligent.
It would be interesting to train a LLM with the books in several dozen, well stocked, seminary libraries from all denominations and even those claiming non-denominational status. Every time I think of the enormous breadth of interpretation that represents (at least about the details; there is a relative level of consensus with highly critical doctrines) my mind is blown.
I also think there's the danger predicted by Francis Schaeffer regarding the permeating erosion of the Christian Consensus within Western society (see "How Should We Then Live").  If you train an LLM with a universe of information largely void of Biblical values, what will you get?
The OP is an interesting question!

Thank you for your answer. Can you expand on the creation part a bit? Because people argue that the AI "creates" texts, that were never written. E.g. I could tell it to write a poem or essay. I'm not sure about a Thesis due to the message restrictions, but how do you think it's impossible for the AI to create a Thesis in the future (let's say 2 years from now)? I do agree there might be a limitation, but I am not so sure.

It's not "create text".  It's create new information that hasn't been expressed before.  You're awarded (or at least supposed to be awarded) a PhD based on ORIGINAL RESEARCH.  The way a Thesis is structured is you first say, "I'm going to show X."  Then, "Here's what everyone else has done.  LLM would probably do this quite well.  The 3rd part is "Here's how I'm going to do this."  This makes visible the methodology of your argument.  And then, finally, "Here's the proof of this 'wow' idea I've come up with."  Look at the hierarchy as if a child is growing up.  First: they remember, and so on.

+1 You make some great points about the nature of information, Mike, which in my view is still poorly understood. However, AI can make inferences, which may or may not be defined as "new" information. As you point out, the universe of information used is critical for the reliability of the result: Garbage in, garbage out. And major scientific progress seems to be made by paradigm shifts rather than incremental progress under the strict control of consensus. Extra kudos for using the superior 2000 revision of Bloom's Taxonomy!

@Dieter Regarding inferences.  Seems to me there's a big difference between these two:  1. "if A then B AND if B then C" infers "If A then C"  2. NT Wright's "New Perspective on Paul" built on observations by JP. Sander's Paul, the Law and Jewish People.  But then again, #1 only uses one AND.  What happens in an LLM when there's hundreds, with ORs, XORs, NANDs, etc..?  I don't know.  Does ChatGPT ever have an "Aha!" or "Eureka" moment where it suddenly "sees" something for the first time?  Probably not.  Maybe it's just a very good conversationalist that would win every Jeopardy game. :-)

@MIke, I agree that the different versions and applications of AI are limited, but the limitations are not as restrictive as one imagines. For example, image recognition develops complex rules to, for example, recognize an image as a "kitten." Generative design can be used to explore new options in urban planning while still following the rules stipulated in a set of specifications. In mechanical design, parts can be optimized for weight and strength (producing organic shapes that can be manufactured only by 3D printing. An ability to challenge assumptions can open new design solutions.

This led me to an interesting discussion with ChatGPT

@telion I suggest a book by Jacques Ellul, The Technological Society.  A summary :  "Ellul argues that modern society is being dominated by technique, which he defines as a series of means that are established to achieve an end. Technique is ultimately focused on the concept of efficiency. The term "technique" is to be comprehended in its broadest possible meaning as it touches upon virtually all areas of life, including science, automation, but also politics and human relations."

Rather than training an LLM on a seminary library, I'd be more interested in a synonymising search engine. Like how Google will bring results about a synonym of your query (or fixing typos in your query!) whereas seminary library catalogues are usually pretty basic and won't match things other than the exact words (and probably won't be full text searches either.) Of course it would also need to allow for exact searches too (like searching for a phrase in quotes in Google.)

@James Shewey, Fascinating conversation. Thank you! Creativity also includes challenging assumptions, facts, and previous conclusions to uncover different interpretations or an entirely new paradigm. Theoretical physicists have been doing exactly this to try to find better models that explain time, entropy, and gravity. In studying the Bible, we often find ourselves questioning what commentators have written or even our own opinions on certain difficult passages when we recognize allusions, learn more about the culture of the ancient Levant, or through discoveries of ancient manuscripts.

It is not possible for LLM to convey the spiritual understanding that the Spirit Himself gives human believers through the study of scripture:
1 Corinthians 2:10-16

But God hath revealed them unto us by his Spirit: for the Spirit searcheth all things, yea, the deep things of God.
11 For what man knoweth the things of a man, save the spirit of man which is in him? even so the things of God knoweth no man, but the Spirit of God.
12 Now we have received, not the spirit of the world, but the spirit which is of God; that we might know the things that are freely given to us of God.
13 Which things also we speak, not in the words which man's wisdom teacheth, but which the Holy Ghost teacheth; comparing spiritual things with spiritual.
14 But the natural man receiveth not the things of the Spirit of God: for they are foolishness unto him: neither can he know them, because they are spiritually discerned.
15 But he that is spiritual judgeth all things, yet he himself is judged of no man.
16 For who hath known the mind of the Lord, that he may instruct him? but we have the mind of Christ.

I personally believe that LLM is/will be another tool of Satan to keep lost souls lost.

In my opinion, the issue isn't so clear. Chatbots are still basically machines. They manipulate electrons that collect, store, retrieve, and manipulate information. In that sense, they're morally neutral. However, like a book, they can condense information and certainly contain errors and lies. Their biggest threat in my opinion is that people put their complete trust in them, which can result in serious consequences as well as good. But the greatest danger is for people to treat them like a god made in the image of man (as in Revelation's image of the beast).

@MarkVestal  Either the "spiritual understandings" is something that is beyond the mind anyway or you have to make an example where an LLM did not convey the spiritual understanding you like to convey. Maybe it would help if you define spiritual understand and compare it to the "normal" understanding that LLM could convey?

@Dieter I agree with the dangers you stated.

@telion Yes. Based on the scripture I cited, spiritual understanding would be beyond the human mind...on its own... without the help of THE Spirit.

@telion Verse 13 in particular. The only way one can discern truth from any medium is to prove it through personal study (proving all things).  The problem is that too many will just blindly follow, but honestly, it is no different than what is happening with bad doctrine and false religion I suppose.

A blind machine will never understand the spiritual word of God.
God's word will never be understood by a cold machine programmed by a cold human who lacks the wisdom of God through spiritual regeneration. AI computes data blindly without applying anything through spiritual direction, because it does not have the wisdom which is present within the heart, the soul, and the spirit of a born-again man of God.
An AI machine system would merely compile the pre-existing mass of data and always biasly choose the majority texts without using any critical hermeneutic comprehension.
I have a fitting set of passages to share with you all:
Joshua 8:18, 8:26, 8:28, 8:29 ESV

Then the LORD said to Joshua, “Stretch out the javelin that is in your hand toward AI, for I will give it into your hand.”
Joshua did not draw back his hand with which he stretched out the
javelin until he had devoted all the inhabitants of AI to destruction.
So Joshua burned AI and made it forever a heap of ruins, as it is to
this day.
And he hanged the king of AI on a tree until evening. And at sunset
Joshua commanded, and they took his body down from the tree and threw
it at the entrance of the gate of the city and raised over it a great
heap of stones, which stands there to this day.

I asked ChatGPT about the name of this city and if there was any connection to the acronym for artificial intelligence. It finally concluded by saying that it was a "fun coincidence" and "just a linguistic quirk"...

Me:
Why does Joshua conquer a city called Ai?
ChatGPT:
According to the biblical narrative in the book of Joshua, the Israelites, led by Joshua, conquered the city of Ai as part of their conquest of the
Promised Land. The story goes that after the Israelites had
successfully crossed the Jordan River into Canaan, they encountered
the city of Jericho, which they famously conquered with divine
assistance, resulting in the walls of Jericho collapsing.
Following their victory at Jericho, the Israelites attempted to
conquer the city of Ai, but they suffered a defeat due to disobedience
to God's command. However, after addressing the issue of disobedience,
Joshua led the Israelites in a second attack on Ai, this time
successfully capturing the city. The conquest of Ai was a significant
event in the Israelites' campaign to claim the land that God had
promised to them.
Me:
Why is the city called "Ai"?
ChatGPT:
The name "Ai" is believed to be derived from the Hebrew word "ʿay" or "ʿi," which means "heap of ruins" or "ruin." This name is fitting considering the fate of the city, as described in the biblical narrative. After the
Israelites conquered the city, they burned it and left it in ruins,
fulfilling the prophecy of its destruction. The name "Ai" thus serves
as a reminder of the city's downfall and the fulfillment of God's
promise to the Israelites.
Me:
Is the name of the city an acronym for Artificial Intelligence?
ChatGPT:
No, the name "Ai" in the biblical context is not an
acronym for "Artificial Intelligence." It predates the modern concept
of AI by thousands of years. The biblical city of Ai is located in the
region of Canaan and is mentioned in the Old Testament of the Bible,
particularly in the book of Joshua. The name "Ai" likely has its
origins in the Hebrew language and carries meanings related to ruins
or destruction, rather than any reference to modern technology like
artificial intelligence.
Me:
AI and AI?
ChatGPT:
Ah, I see what you're getting at! The
connection between "AI" as in "Artificial Intelligence" and "Ai" from
the biblical city might seem coincidental but interesting. The
similarity in the names is purely coincidental, as they come from
completely different contexts and time periods.
"AI" in the modern context stands for "Artificial Intelligence,"
referring to the simulation of human intelligence processes by
machines, especially computer systems. On the other hand, "Ai" in the
biblical context refers to an ancient city in Canaan.
While the similarity in names might be a fun coincidence, there's no
direct connection between the two. It's just a linguistic quirk.
Me: Is it really a coincidence?


Since you meant this answer sarcastically (If I correctly infer that from your comment in the other answer) I recommend making it obvious that it shouldn't be taken seriously. It is not that easy to see that it is meant as a joke, although I had a good laugh after I understood what you did there :)

Actually... ChatGPT does seem to know that Ai does not refer to artificial intellegence in this case. The prompt "What is AI in Joshua 8" returns the result "In the context of the Bible, “Ai” refers to a city that was conquered by the Israelites under Joshua’s leadership. This event is described in detail in the book of Joshua, Chapter 8" and provides 3 citations followed by a summary of the chapter. The LLM is contextually aware.

@JamesShewey ChatGPT said that it was a "fun coincidence" and a "linguistic quirk"...

@JoshuaB - I'm failing to see what you are getting at... Your edit in which you posted your conversation with ChatGPT seems to be making my point - even when pressed the LLM is still able to distinguish the name of the city from the modern acronym.

@JamesShewey - I'm just saying that God defeats AI, through Jesus! Amen.
